# Why doesn't F# support Edit and Continue?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, f#, edit-and-continue

Visual Studio's Edit and Continue and other IDE's equivalent operations are very effective for experimentation in interactive applications, since you don't have to restart the app to see the effects of the code change (most of the time). If Visual Studio already supports this for C#, then why isn't it in F# yet? Does something about F# make it more difficult?

Comment: `Does something about F# make it more difficult?` - probably not, I think there things-with-higher-priority to do.

Comment: Probably because F# code is usually correct when you finish writing it :-) You do not need to fix it during debugging. I'm slightly joking, but there is some true here - REPL with F# interactive and stronger type checking really helps you avoid many bugs early.

Comment: The need for edit and continue is many orders of magnitude smaller in F#, usually when code type checks, it works OK.

Comment: This isn't necessarily opinion-based.  There could be some technical reason that edit-and-continue wouldn't work in F#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It boils down to the fact that this kind of feature needs support in the compiler itself, and since the F# compiler has a much smaller team working on it than the C# compiler, they probably have other, higher priority items to work on.